# High dpi scale and fixing the window size

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I started working on a pyqt GUI and after I saw I need to change the high dpi scaling in order for other screens with different scale and sizes to work I did that and it worked.

From my laptop I can see the same app I'm running as from my laptop. However, the only thing that bother me is that now the size of my GUI takes more then half of my laptop screen and the same GUI takes only like 1\4 or less of my desktop screen.

Is there a way to configure the size of the GUI to trim down accordingly to the screen size without hurting the GUI itself? To be clear - I'm trying to change the size of the GUI now on my laptop to take also 1\4 of the screen without the GUI being destroyed but yet not to change the size of the GUI on my desktop because its the perfect size.

f.e:
[image: screen]

this is how my gui looks using my desktop screen.

and when I use it on my laptop it looks like that :
[image: laptop]
this is the layout of the tabs:(as for right now i didnt use layout for the buttons and ect its just a sample im trying to learn the pyqt..)

```
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    if not MainWindow.objectName():
        MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
    self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
    self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tabWidget.setObjectName(u"tabWidget")
```

and this is how i dealt with the scale :

```
QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: added a picture to try explain it better but i cant get a picture of the laptop at the moment. so this is as best as i can right now. added more explanation below

Comment: Sorry but, while the image is useful, I specifically asked you for a *code example*, as we need to understand how you're implementing the scaling and how widgets are placed (specifically, if and how you're using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)).

Comment: let me know if the recent changes helped. it realy not that much to the code i just dropped some stuff on it (trying to learn the qt)

Comment: Sorry, still not enough. Please read the link I gave you in the first comment: you must provide the *minimal* code that we could copy, paste and run in order to *reproduce* the problem. We also need to see how the UI looks in the other situation, since that's the one that gives you problems.

Comment: hi, i know you asked for a code and ill try and edit that later but i added the other Ui looks in my laptop. hope it helps understanding better.

Comment: I'll wait for the edited code, but, in the meantime some clarifications are required: by seeing your second screenshot, there's almost *no way* that your window could occupy just a quarter of your screen: the space required by your widgets is too big due to the default font size, so, what did you had in mind?

Comment: sorry if im asking some nubs questions but can u explain  what do u mean by that(i am a noob at qt just started using it)? the size of the gui is 800X600  and the font size is like 10. which is not big at all. after i used the scaling option it turned out to be that big in my laptop. as u can see when im running the same gui on my desktop it looks normal. my desktop is 1920x1080 although my laptop is 3800x1600 or something strange like that.

Comment: High DPI works like that: with a given *physical* screen size you can have the same *visible* screen size, but different *pixel* size if the program uses *scaling*. You can see that in your two screenshots: even if your laptop has a bigger resolution, the proportion of the fonts and widgets is *bigger* than those of your desktop. With that assumption, and considering that you should always use the system sizes (widgets and fonts), you cannot have your UI occupying just a quarter of the screen, because it will not fit its contents.

Comment: is there another to approach this problem? f.e have all screen sizes be proportionate  to the gui without the font sizes changing ?  im trying to figure out how to make the same gui for every screen resolution and scaling. if thats even possible. and if not how would u solve this problem.

Comment: You already have the same gui for every resolution and scaling, because it's up to the system to properly scale and resize UI elements in order to provide the user a *readable* and *usable* UI. Trying to *always* resize your UI to a quarter of the screen size will only have results that go from *very bad* to *completely unusable* (for instance, because fonts become too small to be read, or buttons to tiny to be clicked). Just leave it as it is, it's properly shown and it correctly displays every elements by making them visible and usable. **That** should be the *primary* focus of a UI.

Comment: i got what youre saying. i dont need the gui to be  specifically 1\4 of the screen but at the same time i dont need it to be this big. i understand that the current state  is good because it will be resizable and readable in every display res\dpi but my question remains- is there a way to shrink the gui in size without harming the gui itself or there isnt? because although im making the gui itself on 1920x1080 screen and it looks fine its not that usable for laptop users (that whole gui  suppose to be like a small window)